# Disable button if all checkboxes are unchecked and enable it if at least one is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox in each row and a button below it. I want to disable the button if at least one checkbox is checked.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<button type=submit id="confirmButton"> BUTTON </button>
```

The jQuery I came up with to accomplish this is the following:

```
$('tbody').click(function () {
    $('tbody tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.myCheckBox').prop('checked')) {
            doEnableButton = true;
        }
        if (!doEnableButton) {
            $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
        else {
            $('#confirmButton').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Naturally, this does not work. Otherwise I would not be here. What it does do is only respond to the lowest checkbox (e.g., when the lowest button is checked/unchecked the button is enabled/disabled).

I made a JSFIddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fHKJ3/) although it does not show the same behaviour as locally.

Does any know how I can accomplish that it responds to all checkboxes and disables the button if they are ALL disabled?

Comment: You shouldn't mix `.prop` and `.attr` like this. Just use `$('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', !doEnableButton)`.

Comment: You didn't add jQuery as framework in your fiddle, that's why it wasn't the same as locally.

Comment: @DanielLisik Aha! :-)

Comment: @FelixKling what is the second parameter in `prop` (in your case `!doEnableButton`?

Comment: The value you want to assign to the property. The `.disabled` property can have to values, `true` or `false`. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
var checkBoxes = $('tbody .myCheckBox');
checkBoxes.change(function () {
    $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
checkBoxes.change(); // or add disabled="true" in the HTML
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQjZT/)

Explanation, to what I changed:

- Cached the checkbox element list/array to make it a bit faster: `var checkBoxes = $('tbody .myCheckBox');`
- removed the `if/else` statement and used [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change between disable= true/false.
- filtered the cached variable/array `checkBoxes` using [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) so it will only keep the checkboxes that are checked/selected.
- inside the second parameter of prop added a condition that will give `true` when there is more than one checked checkbox, or false if the condition is not met.

Comment: @FelixKling, very true! just added that.

Comment: @user2609980, glad I could help. Added some explanation also.

Answer (score 5):

Add an event handler that fires when a checkbox is changed, and see if there are any checked boxes, and set the disabled property appropriately :

```
var boxes = $('.myCheckBox');

boxes.on('change', function() {
    $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', !boxes.filter(':checked').length);
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fHKJ3/5/)

Comment: However in the final question he formulated it as *"... disables the button if they are ALL disabled"*. If so, than my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHKJ3/1/) might be helpful, since I understood the task exactly in this way.

Comment: THis works like a charm only it is the wrong way around as @VisioN states ;-).

Comment: @user2609980 - Oh okay, I misunderstood the meaning of "disable button if at least one box is checked" then? Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('tbody').click(function () {

   if ($('.myCheckBox:checked').length >= 1) { 
           $('#confirmButton').prop("disabled", true);
       }
   else {
            $('#confirmButton').prop("disabled", false);
   } 

 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fHKJ3/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
let $cbs = $(".myCheckBox").change(function() {
    if ($cbs.is(":checked")){
        // disable #confirmButton if at least one checkboxes were checked
        $("#confirmButton").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        // disable #confirmButton if all checkboxes were unchecked
        $("#confirmButton").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This cannot be the correct answer. Please read the questions carefully when answering!