# Disable button if checkboxes are unchecked - across groups - in an ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

This is an adaptation of [Disable button if all checkboxes are unchecked and enable it if at least one is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687884/disable-button-if-all-checkboxes-are-unchecked-and-enable-it-if-at-least-one-is)

On the above post they are disabling a button unless at least 1 checkbox is checked.

In my situation, I have 2 sets of checkboxes:

```
<div class="clone-ctp__filters">
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Foo 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bar 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Baz 3</label>
</div>

<div class="clone-ctp__users">
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Foo 5</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bar 6</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Baz 7</label>
</div>
```

Followed by a submit button

```
<button>Continue</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is disable the 'Continue' button **unless at least 1 checkbox is checked in both groups** (`.clone-ctp__filters` and `.clone-ctp__users`).

The intention being that the 'Continue' button is only enabled when you have checked at least 1 filter (`.clone-ctp__filters`) and at least 1 user (`.clone-ctp__users`).

The checkboxes themselves have been rendered via an ajax response, i.e. the HTML is written to `.clone-ctp__filters` and `.clone-ctp__users` as the response from 2 separate ajax requests to get the appropriate data.

I've used `ajaxStop` to make sure the code to disable/enable the button fires after the ajax response has completed:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkBoxes.change(function () {
        $('button').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
    });
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change();
});
```

This has the same effect as the linked post. It will disable the button unless at least 1 checkbox is checked. But it has no bearing on which set of checkboxes that's from.

My solution to this was to duplicate the code, e.g.

```
var checkBoxes = $('.clone-ctp__filters input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Then when that completes repeat it with

```
var checkBoxes = $('.clone-ctp__users input[type="checkbox"]');
```

This goes against the principles of DRY. Is there a more elegant way to write this?

jquery 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop (or forEach) would be appropriate.

Additionally make sure you disable the 'submit' if **either** group is unselected (I use `.some` below). Your current code will disable it if the **last** group is unselected.

```
var checkboxGroups = ['clone-ctp__filters', 'clone-ctp__users'].map(containerClass => $(`.${containerClass} input[type="checkbox"]`));
checkboxGroups.flat().forEach(checkbox =>
    checkbox.change(() =>
        $('button').prop('disabled', checkboxGroups.some(checkboxes => checkboxes.filter(':checked').length < 1))));
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change();
```

Or in vanilla JS:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

var checkboxGroups = ['clone-ctp__filters', 'clone-ctp__users']
    .map(containerClass => [...$$(`.${containerClass} input[type="checkbox"]`)]);
    
checkboxGroups.flat().forEach(checkbox =>
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () =>
        $('button').disabled = checkboxGroups.some(checkboxes => checkboxes.every(checkbox => !checkbox.checked))));

$('button').disabled = true;
```

```html
<div class="clone-ctp__filters">
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Foo 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bar 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Baz 3</label>
</div>

<div class="clone-ctp__users">
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Foo 5</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Bar 6</label>
    <input type="checkbox"> <label>Baz 7</label>
</div>

<button>Continue</button>
```

Comment: What is `containerClass`?

Comment: It's defined on line 1 as each element of `['clone-ctp__filters', 'clone-ctp__users']`

Comment: It gives a console error when I've copied/pasted the exact js you've posted above `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkBox is not defined` and doesn't work as in the fiddle

Comment: fixed the case typos (I don't have jquery so I've only tested the vanilla version). Though you should learn to debug simple console errors, or you won't make much progress as a developer.